# Jquery: Hide a link button based on contains in option

Tags: javascript, jquery

**EDIT: Will be more specific with requirements see bottom for additions:**

I am trying to hide an a link (button formatted as a href), however I am trying to do it based on text found with in an option drop down menu.

So for example

```
<form id="phonetypeform">
  <select name="porting-p1" class="dropdown">
     <option value="">Please select an option...</option>
     <option value="1">I want to keep my current phone number</option>
     <option value="2">I want to choose a new number</option>
   </select>
</form>
<a href="#" class="nextbutton">Next Step</a>
```

If the 'please select an option' is selected it hides the a link, if anything else is selected then it shows the link

here is the jquery I have which is not working

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a.nextbutton").hide()

$('.dropdown').change(function() {
    if($('.dropdown option:contains'Please)') {
      $('a.nextbutton',this).hide();
    } else {
      $("a.nextbutton")show();
    }
});

});
```

### EDIT starts here:

thanks to everyone that has given me some answers, but what I now have works, but its not ideal, and ideally would like to use the contains, simple reason is I have about 20 of these scripts I would have to create and target the value, ugly!

to show my exact requirement please see the fiddle, while this is working, as I said I have many of these scripts to put in place, ideally I would like to:
1. target the text 'select...'
2. Have it so that it stays hidden until all options no longer contain 'Select...' (the contains should take care of that right)

Here is a fiddle to make life easier for anyone that can help?
http://jsfiddle.net/p3ewE/

---

END EDIT

Comment: Just missing .show(). The period before calling show()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo here

```
if($('.dropdown option:contains(Please)') 
                               ^      ^
```

[:contains()](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

Use this code

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/nEycK/)

```
$('.dropdown').change(function () {
    if (this.value == "") {
        $('a.nextbutton').hide();
    } else {
        $("a.nextbutton").show();
    }
}).change();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$("a.nextbutton").hide();
$('.dropdown').change(function () {
    if ($('.dropdown').val() == "") {
        $('a.nextbutton', this).hide();
    } else {
        $("a.nextbutton").show();
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/XXDwr/3/)**

You had a few syntax issues with missing periods and brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/XXDwr/5/

have a look at it.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {


    $(".nextbutton").hide();

   $('.dropdown').on('change',function() {
    var h= $('.dropdown').val();
    if(h=="")
    {
          $(".nextbutton").hide();
    }
    else{
          $(".nextbutton").show();
    }

});
});
```

I hope you wanted to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var btnNext = $("a.nextbutton").hide();

  $('.dropdown').change(function() {

      if(this.value){
          btnNext.show();
      } else {
          btnNext.hide();
      }
  });
});
```

You had a typo right before "please".
You could/should save the button in a variable so you don't have to make that query every time.